# I have Windows 10 2004 but WDDM version is 2.0

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

I think that WDDM 2.0 was for the 1st ever windows 10 version and it's update should come with Windows updates which means I should at least be having V2.6.

[image]

Comment: WDDM also requires driver support.  Do you have an Intel display driver that specifically supports 2004?  If you don’t that is the reason WDDM 2.0 is the reported version.  Intels driver support for its legacy products isn’t that good.

Comment: You can try and download the current [driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29474/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-?product=86210) but if you already have it installed you will have to wait for Intel to release a supported driver that specifically supports 2004.  This might not happen due to the fact they are only specifically updating their DCH it seems to support the later Windows releases.

Comment: @Ramhound Will this be fixed if I go back to 1909 and does this cause any performance issues in gaming?

Comment: Have you seen performance problems outside of those expected due to the age of your device?  I don't have a system that only has a legacy Intel iGPU.  I can't say for certain if the current display driver supports 1909.  Since 2004 has not been released it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound I'll definitely give it a shot.

Comment: As has been noted above, WDDM requires driver support. I have V2004 on an older machine with Intel Graphics 4000 and WDDM is at V1.3.  There are no performance issues at all, but you do need a driver update (if there is one) to make WDDM go higher.

Comment: I check two other newer machines and WDDM is at V2.1 .  So it is definitely graphics device and driver dependent .

Comment: Thanks @John I was worried about my PC not performing up to the mark but now I know it's totally driver dependent.